# How can I fix my Powershell code to search for ADGroups in an array?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

My code is as follows:

```
Clear-Host

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$ErrorView = 'CategoryView'

Write-Host 'Searching for ADGroups...'

$ADGroups = @('Remote Desktop Users', 'M365 Migration')

If(Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -In '$ADGroups'") {
    Write-Host 'ADGroups found:'
    Write-Host (Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -In '$ADGroups'") -ForegroundColor Green
}
Else {
    Write-Host 'No ADGroups found' -ForegroundColor Red
}

If(Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -Eq 'Remote Desktop Users'") {
    Write-Host 'Searching for RDLicenseConfiguration...'
    Write-Host (Get-RDLicenseConfiguration -ErrorAction Continue) -ForegroundColor Green

    Write-Host 'Searching for RDDeploymentGatewayConfiguration...'
    Write-Host (Get-RDDeploymentGatewayConfiguration -ErrorAction Continue) -ForegroundColor Green
}

If(Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -Eq 'Remote Desktop Users'") {
    #M365 Migration
    Write-Host 'Searching for applocker policy...'
    Write-Host (Get-AppLockerPolicy -Local -ErrorAction Continue) -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

It works as intended except for the code on line 13, which does not run properly because of incorrect syntax.

I'm currently getting the error:

```
ParserError: (:) [Get-ADGroup], ADFilterParsingException
```

The problem is the code on line 13, I have tried to use `"Name -Like '$ADGroups*'"` although that also didn't work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Need to loop over them. Filter doesn't support -in.

Comment: Thank you Doug I added a Foreach loop over my first code block and this fixed my issue.

Answer (score 3):

The [Active Directory filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server/hh531527(v=ws.10)) doesn't support `-in`, all I had to do was add the `foreach` loop above to cycle through each object in the array and change the comparison operator to `-eq`, thanks again [Doug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4085331/doug-maurer) for the answer.

```
Clear-Host

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$ErrorView = "CategoryView"

Write-Host "Searching for ADGroups..."

$ADGroups = @("Remote Desktop Users", "M365 Migration")

Foreach($group In $ADGroups){
    If(Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -Eq '$group'"){
        Write-Host "ADGroups found:"
        Write-Host (Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -Eq '$group'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name) -ForegroundColor Green
    }
}

If(Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -Eq 'Remote Desktop Users'"){
    Write-Host "Searching for RDLicenseConfiguration..."
    Write-Host (Get-RDLicenseConfiguration -ErrorAction Continue) -ForegroundColor Green

    Write-Host "Searching for RDDeploymentGatewayConfiguration..."
    Write-Host (Get-RDDeploymentGatewayConfiguration -ErrorAction Continue) -ForegroundColor Green
}

If(Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -Eq 'M365 Migration'"){
    Write-Host "Searching for applocker policy..."
    Write-Host (Get-AppLockerPolicy -Local -ErrorAction Continue) -ForegroundColor Green
}
```